# The Source attachment does not contain the source for the file ChartFactory.class

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine-1.0.0 for representing my data in the form of graphs. In the Properties Build path, I gave the path of the jar file. In Order and Import tab I checked the achartengine-1.0.0.jar option. 
  But when debugging my application, still it says "The Source attachment does not contain the source for the file ChartFactory.class". 
  Here is the code,

```
 import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
 import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
 import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
 import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
 import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
 import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
 import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
 import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private static final int SERIES_NR = 2;
  public final android.content.Context Context = MainActivity.this;    


  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   Button ReportGraph=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ReportGraph);
   ReportGraph.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout relChartView=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ChartView);
            GraphicalView GraphChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getApplicationContext(), getDemoDataset(), getDemoRenderer(),Type.DEFAULT);
            //ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(this, getDemoDataset(), getDemoRenderer());
            relChartView.addView(GraphChartView);
        }
    });

}

  private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset() {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    final int nr = 7;
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_NR; i++) {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Demo series " + (i + 1));
        for (int k = 0; k < nr; k++) {
            series.add(k, 20 + r.nextInt() % 100);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series);
    }
    return dataset;
}

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getDemoRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(12);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(12);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
    r.setFillBelowLine(false);
    r.setFillPoints(true);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    setChartSettings(renderer);
    return renderer;
}

private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {
    renderer.setChartTitle("Chart demo");
    renderer.setXTitle("x values");
    renderer.setYTitle("y values");
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(false);
    renderer.setRange(new double[] {0,6,-70,40});
    renderer.setFitLegend(false);
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0.5);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(10.5);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(100);
  }
}
```

Please any one help me. Any help will be appreciated!!!
  Thanks.

Comment: Found the solution!! I decompiled the jar file using JD-GUI decompiler and saved all source files as achartengine-1.0.0.src and added the src path to Build Path. Now I am able to debug my application without any exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the entire AChartEngine source code by following the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/checkout). You don't need to bother decompiling it.